# Storing reference to a prefab in a variable through script (Not by Editor/inspector)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to instantiate a coin prefab that appears when an enemy dies.

To initially get a reference to the prefab, I retrieved it using its tag:

```
private GameObject coinSpawn;
Start(){
    coinSpawn = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("xxx");
}
```

Now when the enemy dies, I call `Instantiate()` as follows:

```
Instantiate(coinSpawn, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
```

However, when I was playing the game and an enemy died, nothing was spawned and I got this error:

> ArgumentException: The Object you want to instantiate is null.

I do not understand what I did wrong - I confirmed that I have properly tagged the prefab which I want to instantiate.

One more thing is that I want to do this without making a `Resources` folder. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag()` only retrieves active GameObjects with the given tag that already exist in the current scene. It sounds like you're trying to use this method to retrieve a reference to a prefab object in your Assets folder, which is something it can't do. As a result, the method is returning null and assigning it to `coinSpawn`, leading to the error when you try to use `coinSpawn` later.

You likely need the [`Resources.Load()`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) method, to which you can supply a path to an object in your Assets folder. Just use that in place of `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag()`:

```
private GameObject coinSpawn;
Start(){
    coinSpawn = Resources.Load("path_to_prefab") as GameObject;
}
```

And yes - you will have to use the name of the prefab instead of its tag to identify it, but I don't think that should pose any problems. (If it does, please update your question accordingly with an explanation.)

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Unity should consider this limitation in their latest version. we will not always create a separate `res` folder to do this !